# Failed to build project with Android studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error with AndroidStudio?

```
Execution failed for task ':sampleapp:preBuild'.
> Build Tools Revision 19.0.0+ is required.
```

I have installed Android Build-tools 19.0.1 from the Android SDK manager

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Check all your `build.gradle` files whether they are using the **19.0.x** version or not.

`buildToolsVersion` will be defined under the `android` tag inside the `build.gradle` file, like this:

```java
android {
     compileSdkVersion 19
     buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

     // Other Configuration
}
```

You can find a list of versions for the Android Build Tools [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html) as well as in the **SDK Manager**.

Comment: make it 19.0.1 and do sync your project with gradle.

Comment: I didn't have 19.0.1 installed, but had 19.0.2. So changing to buildToolsVersion '19.0.2' fixed the failed build. Thanks

Comment: The only thing is what you use should be there installed  in your android sdk and compatible with your android gradle plugin.

Comment: Is there any way to use a wildcard or a plus sign like: buildToolsVersion "19.0.0+"?  It seems cumbersome to manually change the gradle number every single time!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky This is Android we're talking about....One does not simply, add a wildcard and hope things to work.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky ya its good to have but it can be risky sometimes that you won't know which build tools are used to compile your application. Portability of code will be compromised in such cases so Team had disabled it. And I feel its a very fair decision. Kudos to great Tools team.

Comment: @pyus13  I'm not sure how a wildcard will compromise build tools version compatibility.  If anything, it should make it easier to configure.  What would be wrong with allowing "19.+" or "19.0+"?

Answer (score 6):

Go to Window->Android SDK Manager and run it

You will see Android Build-Tools version installed...

Change build.gradle to reflect the installed version of build tools

This worked for me

OR

Install the version which is shown in error

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work for me. I had to update the Default settings then restart the IDE:

1. File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure
2. Under Project Settings: Project,  set Project SDK as Android SDK.
3. Click Edit button
4. For Android SDK, set Build target to Android 4.4.2
5. Click Ok.
6. Restart IDE
7. Then rebuild. Seemed to work after that..

This is assuming you've already installed Android-19 and still having difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the required version of the build tools and it does not work:

Eclipse and the Android Studio likely ***use two different copies of the SDK***, and you have updated the other copy.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your project level build.gradle file and set gradle version to the latest version now it is 3.2.1

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's helpful to remember that you will have build.gradle files for each module in your Android Studio Project.

I kept hitting my head against the wall - "Where the heck is that line everyone's telling me to change?!" - **until I looked in the ~/dev/AndroidProjects/xxprojectnamexx/app folder and looked at the build.gradle file there.**