# android studio - Build failed Input length = 1

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio was working fine couple of days ago.
But now whenever I create a new project in android studio it says `Build: build failed` with `Input length = 1`.
And under Run tasks, there's an error with `:app:processDebugRecources`

Comment: try ->build->rebuild if it didn't work check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21353955/8582361)

Comment: I have the same problem, after moving the project from a Mac Pc to an Windows Pc. Did you solved the problem?

Comment: I did solve the problem, but honestly, I don't remember how I solved it. But I remember that I see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/21353955/8582361

Comment: This error should related with OS's language. If your are using a Windows machine other than english I'm sure you will see this error. The only one solution I can think is  changing the OS language.

Answer (score 1):

In the `build.properties` just add this line:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```